# Почему приложение "API.Яндекс.Карт Подготовка слоя тайлов" привязывает точки карты в 200-300 метрах от реальных (географических координат)?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Привязываю государственную геологическую карту 1:200000 масштаба до 14 уровня приближения через яндексовское приложение, которое еще было прописано для API 1.0. Карта новая второго поколения. Исходное изображение- не скан, из ГИС-системы. Привязываю углы карты с известными географическими координатами. При проверке на готовой страничке выясняется, что сами угловые точки от реальных координат на картах яндекса в стороне на 200-300м, иногда западнее иногда восточнее (короче по произвольному азимуту). Подскажите, может кто сталкивался с такими проблемами при привязке топоосновы к картам Яндекса?

Comment: географические координаты имеют много разных систем для их вычисления. Вполне может быть, что Вы и Яндекс используете разные. Вот пример одной из популярных систем https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WGS_84 (а здесь прям и написано о Вашей проблеме https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BC)

Comment: Все верно. Как бы решить эту проблему без ручной привязки к изгибам речной сети, мысам побережья, высотам и другим удобным меткам?

Comment: понять, какие системы координат используются в каждом случае, найти функцию преобразования и поправить свои координаты.

Comment: http://dspk.cs.gkovd.ru/library/data/Doc_9674_r_vo_po_vsemirnoy_geodezicheskoy_sisteme__1984_%28WGS_84%29.pdf На странице 128 нашел разложения для проекции Меркатора и понял, что легче руками:))